# Uncaught Reference Error in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery that is calling a CropBox (to crop an iamge dynamically). All seems to work fine with no errors until after the crop has happened then I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: recalculateCropBoxHeight is not defined
recalculateCropBoxHeight();
```

The pertinent code is:

```
$('#open_admin_crop_window_button').on('click', function() {
myWidth = $('#cropbox').width();

recalculateCropBoxHeight();

function recalculateCropBoxHeight() {
    // CHECK IF myWidth HAS RETURNED A PERCENTAGE INSTEAD OF PIXELS
    if( myWidth < 100 ) {
        myWidth = $(window).width()/(100/myWidth);
    }


    if(imgw > myWidth) {
    widthRatio = imgw/myWidth;
    myHeight = imgh/widthRatio;
    } else {
        myHeight = imgh;
    }
    xsize = imgw;
    ysize = imgh;   
}

runCropBox();

});


function cropSuccess(data) {
    var returnedData = JSON.parse(data);
        if(!returnedData.error) {
            jcrop_api.destroy();
            recalculateCropBoxHeight(); // ERROR HAPPENING HERE
            runCropBox();                
        }
}
```

Apologies if my jquery/javascript isn't up to much. I'm very new to this. I will be happy to take suggestions around this but if you could see why this code is giving me the error it would be much appreciated.

As I mentioned, the strange thing is that the code is working fine.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are running into a scope issue. Because you are defining your function inside of the `on click` event, the function `cropSuccess(data)` function does not see it as a valid function. Pull the `recalculateCropBoxHeight` function out of the event and it should be able to call it.

Answer (score 1):

`recalculateCropBoxHeight` is declared inside another function. It is not a global. It does not exist in the scope you are trying to call it from.

Move it outside that function. It appears to only touch variables that are globals anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You and miriye both answered at the same time. I've put miriye as the 'accepted answer' simply because he hasn't got as much reputation and badges as you, not as a reflection of the quality of your answer :-)